# Reuse conditional select in SQL

Tags: sql

Im trying to create an SQL query that does something as the following:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN a + b IS NULL a
    ELSE b
  END AS derived,
  c / derived as new1,
  sum(derived + d) as new2
FROM mytable
JOIN ...
WHERE ...;
```

However the problem im having is that it seemes there is no way to actually reference an earlier alias in a `SELECT`. What is the idiomatic way to solve this in SQL?

Comment: Is this oracle, mysql or Sql server?

Comment: use the same case expression where you used derived. So instead of derived use the whole case expression except for `AS derived`

Answer (score 0):

Alas, aliases are not available for reuse in the `SELECT` statement in which they were defined, for any database, as far as I know.  So I think you will have to simply repeat the logic of the `CASE` expression if you require it in the same `SELECT` statement.

If you want to avoid this, the best you might be able to do using normal SQL techniques would be to subquery a query which defines the `derived` column and reuse it that way, e.g.

```
SELECT t.derived,
       t.c / t.derived      AS new1,
       SUM(t.derived + t.d) AS new2
FROM
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN a + b IS NULL THEN a ELSE b END AS derived,
           c, d
    FROM mytable
) t
```

Comment: I have multiple joins and where in the from, updated example to show better.

Comment: @user3139545, the same derived table idea will help you anyway.

Comment: This wouldn't really change my answer.  Either you reuse it, or subquery if that is acceptable to you.  It would be acceptable if you already happen to have a subquery structure or you can tolerate the query running more slowly, or both.

Answer (score 0):

Just by putting a outer select block you can do it. See below:

```
  with abc as (select derived,
                  c / derived as new1,
                  sum(derived + d) as new2
                from 
                (SELECT 
                  CASE 
                    WHEN a + b IS NULL then a
                    ELSE b
                  END AS derived,
                  c,
                  d
                FROM mytable ) )
  select a.*,<column list>
  from abc a
  join ...
  WHERE ....;
```

Comment: I have multiple joins and where in the from, updated example to show better.

Comment: I use the result as CTE and make further joins. Check updated

Answer (score 0):

I often move such calculations to a CROSS APPLY, appended after the last JOIN. The derived column is then available for use in SELECT, GROUP BY and ORDER BY.

```
SELECT 
  derived,
  c / derived as new1,
  sum(derived + d) as new2
FROM mytable
JOIN ...
CROSS APPLY (   SELECT CASE 
                         WHEN a + b IS NULL a
                         ELSE b
                       END AS derived
            ) AS d(derived)
WHERE ...;
```

Comment: Will execute only in Oracle 12c i guess. CROSS APPLY is a feature of Oracle 12c

Comment: @XING: CROSS APPLY is also supported in SQL Server and Postgres (which uses the SQL standard's `LATERAL` instead of `APPLY`)

Comment: Ohh..i see..then it make sense coz database name is not properly tagged